# Hiding pixel of one layer based on pixel value of other layer

Tags: raster, visualisation, band

I have a raster layer that contains multiple bands. I want to visualize one band in particular, but only the pixels that have a value of 0.6 or higher in another band of the same raster layer should be shown. I have tried using the CON command in raster calculator, but this hasn't proven succesful as of yet.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using QGIS raster calculator, use this expression to return pixels of band1 if band 2 and 3 are bot > 0.6:

```
("raster@3">0.6) * ("raster@2">0.6) * "raster@1"
```

Be aware - the just released QGIS version 3.22 Białowieża has a new `if` function in the raster calculator - [see changelog](https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.22/#add-if-function-raster-calculator). This will make use of raster calculator easier to use from now on.

**Explanation:**

The expression returns the pixels of band 1 (`"raster@1"`) of the raster layer called `raster`, but only if band 2 (`"raster@2"`) and band 3 (`"raster@3"`) are both > 0.6.

`("raster@3">0.6)` returns 1 if band 3 > 0.6, otherwise 0:

- If it is 0, multiplication with other values still results to 0.
- If it is one, multiplication will return the value of the second factor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible 'on the fly', but you can use GDAL r.reclass

```
0 thru 0.6 = 0
0.6 thru YOUR_MAX_VALUE = 1
```

or QGIS raster calculator for create new raster with values based on any band you want.